# Hook calls within a loop always get the Entry, not the loop context?

Tags: plugin-development, templating, hook

According to [the docs](http://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/services/TemplatesService#hook-detail), if I call a hook from within my template:

> The $context argument will be the current Twig context array, which you’re free to manipulate.

So I have a loop in my template where summary is a model I've created:

```
{% for summary in bookings %}
    {% hook 'microsGetBooking' %}
{% endfor %}
```

If I understand correctly, the $context variable passed to my hook should be a reference to that summary object. However it always appears to be an EntryModel (in this case the template I'm calling this on has a URL that matches an entry in the CMS).

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

> If I understand correctly, the $context variable passed to my hook should be a reference to that summary object.

Nope... `$context` is a reference to the entire Twig rendering context of which your `bookings` objects will be a part of.

You can use xDebug or `var_dump` to see where your `bookings` objects are stored and loop though them as necessary from PHP.